# How to get CRM Global Picklist values using Talend?

Tags: talend

We have a custom entity with few Global Picklists in CRM.  How to design a job in Talend to extract global picklist values from CRM and output to a Sql Server table?

Answer (score 0):

Are you speaking about salesforce?
If so, tSalesforce components are not able to provide you these informations.
However, thank's to the flexibility of Talend Open Studio and thank's to the salesforce Metadata API, you can do it by yourself yourself with a little piece of Java code.

Comment: Do you have a java code that I can use to extract this?  This is coming from Dynamics 365.